# Migrating 10-15 Websites Running Linux, LAMP, RoR, WordPress

Tags: linux, migration

My task is to move 10-15 websites running on Linux webservers to new servers hosted by Amazon.  These boxes are currently on dedicated servers.  Some sites are running WordPress, some have custom CMS, and others might have RoR applications.

Unfortunately, there is sparse documentation regarding each site and how services/files are dependent on each other, which means there is a lot of detective work that needs to take place.

My goal is to properly document each site, what makes them work, etc., so future admins have at least something to work with.

Currently my strategy is to download each site so I have a backup of the files then scan through them looking for configuration files, DB connections, apache configs, etc., then create a nice spreadsheet with these findings and migrate these out to the new server.

My question to ServerFault is this what things you would look out for, and are there easier ways to handle this task that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Blueprint](https://github.com/devstructure/blueprint) can help you reverse-engineer your servers' configuration (packages installed, apache config, other service configurations), and it can also generate Puppet manifests and Chef recipes to make it easier to set up the new servers.